# ASP.Net wont launch - IIS error because it's not in root?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a ASP.Net solution that I have checked out of SVN. I have saved it under `c:\inetpub\solution-name\`. The file I am trying to launch is in `c:\inetpub\solution-name\trunk\project-name\Default.aspx`. When I access that via the browser `http://localhost/solution-name/trunk/project-name/`, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 253:      </controls>
Line 254:    </pages>
Line 255:    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
Line 256:      <providers>
Line 257:        <clear/>
```

I think the problem might have something to do with the directory structure of the files. I don't want to change the structure as I need to be able to have multiple solutions under `inetpub`, etc.

Is there an IIS configuration to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **Virtual Directory** for each Asp.Net project in IIS. Also if you are on IIS7+ you can right click on folder and click on "Convert to Application". To create a virtual directory you can right-click on the website in IIS, and select "Add Virtual Directory".

Comment: I tried to `Add Virtual Directory`. I entered an `Alias` and `Physical path:` (I'm not sure what this should be, but I pointed it to the folder of my default project). When I clicked on `Test Settings`, the `Authentication` seems to have passed, but the `Authorization` returned this:

Comment: "The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again."